# Neo4j Bolt StatementResult to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, neo4j

Based on example from [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/)

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

  driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo4j"))
  session = driver.session()

  session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})")

  result = session.run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title")
  for record in result:
      print("%s %s" % (record["title"], record["name"]))

  session.close()
```

Here `result` is of datatype `neo4j.v1.session.StatementResult`. How to access this data in pandas dataframe **without explicitly iterating**?

`pd.DataFrame.from_records(result)` doesn't seem to help.

This is what I have using list comprehension

```
resultlist = [[record['title'], record['name']] for record in result]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(resultlist, columns=['title', 'name'])
```

Answer (score 10):

The best I can come up with is a list comprehension similar to yours, but less verbose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([r.values() for r in result], columns=result.keys())
```

The [`py2neo`](http://py2neo.org/v3/) package seems to be more suitable for DataFrames, as it's fairly straightforward to return a list of dictionaries.  Here's the equivalent code using `py2neo`:

```
import py2neo

# Some of these keyword arguments are unnecessary, as they are the default values.
graph = py2neo.Graph(bolt=True, host='localhost', user='neo4j', password='neo4j')

graph.run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})")

query = "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title"
df = pd.DataFrame(graph.data(query))
```

Comment: py2neo does not do much more than your list comprehension when calling `.to_data_frame` on the result

Answer (score 8):

Casting result records into dictionaries does the trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(record) for record in result])
```

Comment: Works great! This should be accepted as the answer. Very clean, neat, and Pythonic.

Comment: agree, simplest + shortest.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
from pandas import DataFrame

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("",""))

get_instances = """MATCH (n)--(m)
                   RETURN n
                   LIMIT 10
                   """

with driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
    result = graphDB_Session.run(get_instances)
    df = DataFrame(result.records(), columns=result.keys())
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the `V4` of `py2neo`, the conversion to pandas DataFrame is even easier.

```
    import py2neo

    # Some of these keyword arguments are unnecessary, as they are the default values.
    graph = py2neo.Graph(uri, user=username, password=password)

    df = graph.run("Your query goes here").to_data_frame()
```